# How to get first value from this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Im trying to get by subquery clientId of customer with most orders but only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
 SELECT a.ClientName 
FROM Clients as a 
INNER JOIN Orders as b 
    ON a.Id=b.ClientId 
WHERE b.ClientId 
 IN(SELECT b.ClientId,COUNT( b.ClientId) as MAKS FROM Orders as b 
    GROUP BY b.ClientId ORDER BY MAKS DESC)
```

Do we have some tools to handle this and how can i optimize this query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you want to display all customers with their max orders? or only get one customer?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu i want to get only 1 customer which made the most orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Top 1, Count and Group By

SQL Server

```
SELECT Top 1 a.ClientName , count(b.orders_id) TotalOrders
FROM Clients as a 
INNER JOIN Orders as b 
    ON a.Id=b.ClientId 
GROUP BY a.client_name
order by TotalOrders desc
```

MySQL

```
SELECT a.ClientName , count(b.orders_id) TotalOrders
FROM Clients as a 
INNER JOIN Orders as b 
    ON a.Id=b.ClientId 
GROUP BY a.client_name
order by TotalOrders desc
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the inner join because you are asking for an ID that is the same in both tables,

```
SELECT ClientName FROM Clients
WHERE Id = (SELECT TOP 1 ClientId FROM Orders 
GROUP BY ClientId
ORDER BY COUNT(ClientId) DESC)
```